# I have seen this code to prevent the form resubmission on page reloading

Tags: javascript, web-development-server, visual-web-developer-2010

I don't understand the logic in the following js-code. When will it be triggered? When does the condition apply, etc.?

```js
if (window.history.replaceState) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
}
```

I do understand, that `replaceState()` actually replaces the URL and hence does not add another page to the history but when and why will it be triggered? What does `if (window.history.replaceState)` do?

Comment: The History.replaceState() method modifies the current history entry, replacing it with the stateObj, title, and URL passed in the method parameters. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState

Comment: ```if(window.history.replaceState)``` it checks method exists or not

Answer (score 0):

### What does the `if (window.history.replaceState)` do:

It will evaluate the inner part of the if-condition (the parenthesis) and check if the value that it returns is `true`. If this actually is the case, then it will execute the code block inside the `curly-brace: {}`.

In JavaScript, there is no type-safety. The type of a variable is always inferred by the value it holds.

`window` is an object and so is `history`. History is a property of the `window object`.

[image: window.history example]

`replaceState` refers to a function that is defined on the history object (again, as a property). In the if-statement context, it means:

> "Please check the history property on object window and see if the replaceState function exists".

If it does not exists, it will return return `undefined`. `Undefined` and `null` are both being evaluated as `false` i.e. typecast of `undefined` or `null` to a `boolean`. This is casting is referred to as `type coercion`.

[image: boolean coercion]

If it is defined, however, then it will return `true` and the `if-condition` applies. In this case, history will be an object and therefore it will evaluate as `true`. You can read more about type coercion if you are interested.

Should be easy to understand: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/